# Htaccess file to protect files on the server

Tags: .htaccess, download

I created a php script that allows you to download and upload files. Files are saved to a directory XXX. Can I add an htaccess file to protect files in this folder? I would want that people must login to my web site to download files. I would want that people who know the position of XXX can not download file without to login to control panel of my web site. What should I write in this htaccess file? The site is hosted. Files can have any extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in your htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^files/([^/]+)/([^/]+).zip /download.php?folder=$1&file=$2 [NC]
```

All requests to `files/XXX/YYY.zip` will be rewritten to `files/download.php?folder=XXX&file=YYY` and your php can handle the authentication.